# The "cannot launch avd in emulator"

Tags: android, android-studio, android-emulator, android-virtual-device

Recently I started studying programming in android studio. I have a bug when IO try to start the Emulator that says: 
*ko:Could not create temp file for system partition image:    %s,size=0x%llx*
[ko:Could not create temp file for system partition image: %s,size=0x%llx](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Afy0a.png)
I've already tried to find a solution in the internet - installing HAX (intel) but it didn't help.
I've no clue what to do.. Please help!

Answer (score 1):

If you have an AMD processor, the intel emulator doesn't usually work. Some suggest running the setup manually by launching **{SDK_FOLDER}\extras\intel\Hardware_Accelerated_Execution_Manager\intelhaxm.exe**
but installing an alternative emulator (I use Genymotion) is a sure solution.

First, download Genymotion here: https://www.genymotion.com/#!/download.
Genymotion requires Virtualbox to be installed (you can install both as a bundle on the Genymotion website),

Then in Android Studio, go to File>Settings>Plugins>Browse repositories and search for and download the Genymotion plugin (this is optional). If you have files on different drives, the plugin in Android Studio may not work, so you'd have to launch Genymotion separately.

You can create an AVD in Genymotion just like with the stock intel emulator. When you run your Genymotion AVD then run your app, the AVD will show in Android Studio.